# How to plot 2 variables against each other using a bar chart in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, bar-chart

In a pandas dataframe, I have three columns:

| Column | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Educational level | `Bachelors` , `Masters` , `PHD` , ... |
| Education-num | `1` , `2` , `3` , ... |
| salary | `1` , `0` |

I want to plot a barchart with `count` on the y-axis. And on the x-axis, `educational level` with `salary`. How can I do so with `matplotlib` or `seaborn`?

[image: plot]

I have tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv("ds.csv")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.barplot(ax = ax, data = df, x = 'EDUCATION-NUM', y = 'SALARY')

plt.show()
```

But it was not what I want.

Comment: please provide a sample of your data. You can do that by copy pasting the result of `print(df.head(10))` (do not post it as image)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some manipulation to generate `count` that is in your chart. Is it from 'EDUCATION-NUM'?

Once generated:

`x = 'Education level'`
`y = 'count'`

to segment, you use `hue = 'SALARY'`

documentation is here: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html

Comment: How can I generate count? Yes, count refers to EDUCATION-NUM which are in a certain salary category '1' or '0' since I will segment it by SALARY.

Comment: without showing some example data we can not guess how to calculate data of yours.

Comment: as @Rabinzel says, what are you trying to count?